# How do I transform a standard text tag into a button on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want a button that appears as standard text but transforms into the standard button styling when hovered over.

[image: 3d button]

This is what I mean by 3D button. In other words, the default button that appears on most browsers when you create a  tag in html.

What I have now is:

```
button{
margin:5px;
background-color:white;
border:0px;
}
...

<button > Home </button>
```

Update: In response to your comments, generating a new 3D background and border from scratch is not exactly what I had in mind (that's sort of what I meant by importing an image being obvious), but that might solve my problem anyways. It sounds like there isn't a built in way to display a default 3D button on hover, without generating a new image

edit: To clarify I want the button to go to the "default styling" (pictured above) on hover. When not hovered on, it should appear as specified in the above CSS - in other words plain text. Replace any mention of "default 3D button" with "standard button."

Comment: What do you mean by "3D background"? DO you have examples of what you are trying to achieve?  Do you know the CSS you want to apply, just now how to make it appear on hover condition?  It is not really clear what your current roadblock is here.

Comment: Please add the CSS and HTML that you will use to make it appear as normal text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to apply styling when the button is not hovered over use the **negation pseudo-class**.

```css
button:not(:hover) {
  background: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
```

Comment: great answer! I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an item to a button with jQuery and Bootstrap. This would be the easiest way.

HTML:

```
<a class="centered" href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
}

a:hover{
   text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-default{
   border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a').hover(
       function(){ $(this).addClass('btn-default') },
       function(){ $(this).removeClass('btn-default') }
)
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/gajqWd/)

Comment: I didn't think of generating a new background, I'd assumed that you would need to import an image. What if you wanted the button's appearance to be browser dependent, i.e. based on the default button of any browser, rather than generated programmatically?

Comment: you can do it all in CSS, you can even apply a gradient if you wanted. No need for an external image! In the demo I applied a box shadow as well to give it a more 3d feel. They are going to look the same, this is standard HTML & CSS.

Comment: I've tested a 3d button on all browesers except safari and they look the same. Just to be sure xP

Comment: No offense but in your example the button doesn't look like the default 3D button when you hover (if Codepen displayed it correctly for me). I want it to look _exactly_ like the default 3D button that I have in my main post.

Comment: That's because based on your initial question you wanted a 3d button, http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/JYBxoR take a look at that button on this pen. It's the default styling without any added CSS. As you can see it's not 3d on hover or not. If you want to create a button that is 3d you'll have to style it to be 3d

Comment: I did say "the default 3d button," so the word default should have thrown you off from that but I guess that was confusing. What I want is for the button to start off with the CSS in my main post (appearing as text) and then turn into the "default styling button" when you hover over it.

Comment: Thank you that was much clearer and I have a solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very basic 'button' with CSS. I just used the built in CSS :hover effect and add some basic style to the anchor element.

```css
#button {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 45px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  }

#button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, silver); 
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, silver); 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, silver); 
  background: linear-gradient(white, silver);
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0), 0px 9px 25px rgba(1,0,0,1); 
  color: black;
  }
```

```html
<a href='#' id='button'>Click</a>
```